# Ubuntu 18.04 change boot depending on availability HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04

I am using a small system hard coded to boot from SD card.  I have created a few scripts to automatically copy the OS to the connected harddrive and change the boot.ini file to boot from the HDD during the next boot.  All is working fine.
When there is a problem with the HDD, the system will continue to try to boot from HDD and it will fail completely.
Is there a way to detect the availability of the HDD and then mount either the SD or the HDD to the root of the filesystem?  This test would need to happen during the pre-boot phase.
Please note that the system has no keyboard or screen attached and so the detection should be fully automated.

Thanks

PS: Would it be possible to default boot from SD, check existence of HDD, then change boot.ini and reboot.
Once booted, I would first need to change the original boot.ini back so that during the next boot (if something goes wrong with the HDD), the system is still able to boot with the original boot.ini which would load the system from SD card rather than from the HDD.